# Performance issue when writing to google docs sheet via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use apps script to connect to an SQL database and execute a query. It works as intended but writing the result to a docs sheet takes too long. The execution exceeds the timeout long before all rows are written. The query itself is executed relatively fast (<10s) but writing the lines (over 12000 results) happens very slowly. I use the following code:

```
var server = 'x.x.x.x';
var port = 3306;
var dbName = 'xxx';
var username = 'xxx';
var password = 'xxx';
var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+server+':'+port+'/'+dbName;
 
function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('insertQueryHere');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet123');
 sheet.clearContents();
 var arr=[];
 
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }
 
 sheet.appendRow(arr);
 
while (results.next()) {
 arr=[];
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
 }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);
}
 
results.close();
stmt.close();
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);
}
```

Any idea on how to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making repeated calls to the server with `appendRow()`.  Instead collect all the new rows in an array and use `setValues()`.  See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

```
function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('insertQueryHere');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet123');
 sheet.clearContents();
 var arr=[];
 var rows = [];
 
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }
 
 rows.push(arr);
 
while (results.next()) {
 arr=[];
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
 }
 rows.push(arr);
}

sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,numCols).setValues(rows);
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // just to make sure the data is written
 
results.close();
stmt.close();
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely improves execution time by enough to make it work. But the code writes the exact same value in all rows and columns. I would be extremely thankful if you could help me find the error. I expect it to be just one simple mixup somewhere but was not able to find yet.

Comment: Sorry I miss typed `setValue` should be `setValues`